# How do I setblock a command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I setblock a command block that's repeating, always active, and has a command? I need it for a one command block creation.

Comment: Isnt there a always active settings when you make a command inside a command block?

Answer (score 1):

1.12-:

```
setblock <x> <y> <z> repeating_command_block 0 replace {Command:"Command",auto:1b}
```

1.13+:

```
setblock <x> <y> <z> repeating_command_block{Command:"Command",auto:1b}
```

You can also just change the command block configuration inside the command block GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest making a single command block creation in game - try either notepad or this handy tool; https://mrgarretto.com/commanddump

If you where wondering, `/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~ ~0 ~1 ~ ~-1 ~1 redstone_block"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"`**your command**`"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:stone,Time:1}}}}` is a good start since it can be manipulated for multiple commands.

For example, two commands:
`/summon FallingSand ~ ~1 ~ {Block:redstone_block,Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"/fill ~ ~0 ~1 ~ ~-3 ~1 redstone_block"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"`**Command 1**`"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"\n"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:command_block,TileEntityData:{Command:"`**Command 2**`"},Time:1,Riding:{id:"FallingSand",Block:stone,Time:1}}}}}}`

I don't suggest having a repeating command block placed somewhere for a one command block creation.